# If i set up a random ip manually will i be able to browse internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

I am using ubuntu and if manually give a random ip will i be able to browse internet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the question? You set your gateway to be (probably) your local routers address, and you probably have a soho/personal router that just does not care about local IP ranges. It sees your requests and forwards them and gives them back... probably setup by the factory like that so it "just works".

Comment: @number 9 thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Given that there is no working IPv6 configuration and the output of the second image shows the routing table before you start assigning random IP addresses, your chance that you'll be able is about 253 / 4294967296 (0.00000005890615284442) or less. The address in your first image won't work.

The problem is that your computer needs a gateway to access the internet. It must know how to contact the gateway as well as the gateway must know how to contact your computer. The gateway (with address 192.168.1.1) probably knows how to contact devices with addresses from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254 in your local network, that's where the number 253 comes from. All in all there are 2^32 (4294967296) addresses in IPv4 possible. You divide the smaller number by the bigger and get the probability that your truly random address would fit.

Comment: I gave a dns 8.8.8.8 in the router and it worked ..thanks for your help

Comment: @somanraj Note that the address of the DNS server has nothing to do with what addresses would be valid for your machine.